# c++ is it valid to return pointer to static array defined inside function?

Tags: c++

I have some c++ piece of code that looks like this

```
StatusMessage foo() {
  ...
  if(errorCondition) {
    return StatusMessage("some custom error message");
  } else {
    return StatusMessage::OK;
  }
}
```

The constructor of StatusMessage takes a const char* and stores the pointer of it.

Now I would like to return a formatted string, however.

I assume the following would likely lead to a crash since the memory of not_ok is only valid during the scope of this function.

```
StatusMessage foo() {
  ...
  if(errorCondition) {
    char not_ok[512];
    sprintf(not_ok, "some custom error message with additional detail: %d", someInt);
    return StatusMessage(not_ok);
  } else {
    return StatusMessage::OK;
  }
}
```

Now, while I know the following is not clean and will overwrite the content of older StatusMessage values if the method is executed multiple times, I wonder if this is generally safe in terms of memory access (unless the message overflows the buffer):

```
StatusMessage foo() {
  ...
  if(errorCondition) {
    static char is_this_ok[512];
    sprintf(is_this_ok, "some custom error message with additional detail: %d", someInt);
    return StatusMessage(is_this_ok);
  } else {
    return StatusMessage::OK;
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on what Status message does. I assume it's some class, that has a cosntructor that takes `const char *` as paramter? Does it copy that string or just store the pointer?

Comment: If the `StatusMessage` class stores just the pointer itself, then the `static` array is fine. *But* note that technically you're not really storing a pointer to the array, but rather only a pointer to the first element (character) of the array.

Comment: @Bob oops, it was a typo

Comment: At least make is_this_ok thread_local so you don't get races from different threads using `foo()` at the same time

Answer (score 6):

This will work, and it is safe, but every instance of `StatusMessage` you create here will share the same string, so it will lead to messy code no one wants to deal with. A better thing to do is to copy the string in `StatusMessage` constructor. Use a `std::string` to manage the memory and it should work flawlessly.

If you can't change the code in `StatusMessage`, the solution you got there may be good enough. It depends on what you want to do. Another option is creating a wrapper class of some sort.

Comment: The thing is I can't change the code of the StatusMessage class. It takes a const char* as argument and stores the pointer to it.

Comment: Storing every message might require considerable memory and you can't remove elements safely, because you don't know which elements are still in use somewhere.

Comment: @churill you're right. OP should really consider a wrapper class of some sort.

Comment: Can you change foo() to return a tuple of StatusMessage and allocated string (can be std::string with `StatusMessage(erorr_text.c_str())`)? Then you code can delete the string when the StatusMessage expires.